# Heroku API: Add collaborator to app and set his permissions to Deploy, Operate and Manage

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I am using [Heroku's Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) to create apps and I am adding collaborators to the app by calling [Collaborator Create](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#collaborator-create), passing the app name and collaborator's email.

It works but the issue is that I can't set the collaborator's privileges directly through the API call, the collaborator just has `View` permissions on the app but I also want him to have `Deploy` and `Operate`.

I tried sending extra parameters but Heroku rejects and returns 422.

Is this a limitation of the API? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, use the [Team COllaborator Create](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#team-app-collaborator-create)